# How to keep the content of my page below the navbar, regardless of screen height?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, screen-orientation

I am trying to place the content of my homepage below my navabr which is located at the center of the page.
I was able to place the content below the navbar, but it changes when I change the window's height.
How do I make it stick below the navbar?
this is the css:

```css
.content {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.homeNav {
    transition: 0.3s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
}

.homeContent {
    position: absolute;
    transition: 0.3s;
    top: 65%;
}
```

This is my html:

```html
<body>
    <div class="container content">
        <nav class="homeNav" id="all">
            <img src="/images/400x200.png" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" />
            <div class="row bg-info">

             NAVIGATION BAR HERE

            </div>
        </nav>
        <div id="main-page" class="homeContent">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Please note that this is a single-page application, and the content of the `main-page` is obtained from a separate HTML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add css to the body element

```
body{
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

That's it.
Alternatively, you can wrap the header and bottom content in a `div` and then give `margin-top` to that `div` element.

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <nav>Header Area</nav>
   <!-- Everything else goes here -->
</div>
```

CSS for wrapper class:

```
.wrapper{
   margin-top: 200px;
}
```